# Google Voice automatically accepting outgoing call

Tags: c#, gmail, google-voice

I'm trying to make a program that calls a person using Google Voice when some condition is met.

I'm using SharpVoice to perform the call. The problem is that I have to have Gmail opened and then I have to manually accept that the outgoing call is happening.

I would like it to send the call automatically so I can just stay where I am without having to go to my desktop to accept the outgoing call.

Comment: consider using http://www.twilio.com/?

Comment: @JDwyer I haven't. Have you used it? It's not free though, right?

Comment: Right, it costs money. I have never tried automating Google voice phone calls so it may be possible to do what you are wanting. I have used twillo and you can do some pretty neat things, make phone calls, text to speech, option trees (press 1 to ...), callbacks to your code for various events. https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto

Comment: Use selenium perhaps ?